# facebook login , FB.getLoginStatus() not working properly

Tags: javascript, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

i am trying to integrate a facebook login to my web site  when i use the `getLoginStatus()` it never returns **not_authorized**, it's either **connected** or **unknown** even when i use the `logout` method it returns **unknown**,here is the code i use:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
alert("you are connected")`} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
alert(" not authenticated your app");`} else {
alert("isn't logged in to Facebook.");});
```

Comment: You know that you commented out big parts of your code by converting it into a string literal ` ` ...

Comment: Sorry it's ma first  post on this website x)

Answer (score 0):

i just want to say that i started another app with a new APP ID and  now everything works fine.